# Not able to display Qlabel on PyQt4

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, qlabel

Hi i have posted the code below through which i'm unable to display label in pyqt4. Any suggestions would be helpful .

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import sys

class Entry_view(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setGeometry(25, 25, 800, 480)

        label = QtGui.QLabel()
        label.setText("Welcome To Python GUI")
        label.resize(100, 50)
        # label.show(self)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
app     = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp = Entry_view()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code below is the solution ,

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import sys

class Entry_view(QtGui.QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setGeometry(25, 25, 800, 480)

    label = QtGui.QLabel()
    label.setText("Swipe The Card")
    vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    vbox.addWidget(label)
    vbox.addStretch()
    self.setLayout(vbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app     = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp = Entry_view()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not keep a reference to the label, so it got garbage-collected before it could be shown. Try this instead:

```
self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
self.label.setText("Welcome To Python GUI")
self.label.resize(100, 50)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why did you set the text but don't process the app using thus:

```
app.processEvents() # On the QApplication.
```

Or just do:

```
label = QtGui.QLabel(text="Welcome to Python GUI!")
```

Or:

```
label = QtGui.QLabel("Welcomme To Python GUI!")
```

Or another way is:

```
label.show() # No widgets on it.
```